# How can I get docker running on win 365 business edition vitrual pc?

Tags: windows, docker

It installs and Virtual Machine Platform is turned on in windows features but it still gives me this error when run: Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.

It's business edition so I don't have access to bios or any of the internals.  Microsoft support was less than useless.